# Command line streaming string manipulation from netcat

Tags: udp, netcat

I have a netcat udp connection listening with `nc -l -u ...`. I've been trying to do a per packet manipulation of the incoming data with just command line, but it doesn't look like there is a flag in `netcat` to indicate a new packet.

First, is it possible to just apply a new line to the end of each packet coming in from netcat?

If not, is there a way instead to match a string and output a new line while netcat is streaming in data?

Comment: You won't be able to distinguish a UDP packet that contains a newline from two separate UDP packets. Try if one of [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/)'s plethora of options solves your problem, but you may need to move on to Perl/Python/Ruby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Server side:

```
# nc -l -u -p 666 > /tmp/666.txt
```

Other server side's shell:

```
# tail -F /tmp/666.txt | while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "$line";
    # do what you want.
  done;
```

Client side:

```
# nc -uv 127.0.0.1 666

#### Print your commands.
```

Answer (score 0):

This wrapper did the trick for me:

```
while :; do
   nc -l -u -p 666 -W 1
   echo
done
```